# Set parameters for Linux Full Disk Encryption?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, luks, dm-crypt

How do I change the parameters (algorithm, hash, key-lengh, block-size, IVs, mode-of-operation, key-derivation function etc.) for the encryption being used by Linux built in Full Disk Encryption (System Encryption)?

**EDIT :** I want to use **native Rijndael** instead of 'AES' cipher, since using Rijndael allows more options to set instead of AEStandard. Is this somehow possible? E.g. mcrypt (i think) provides native Rijndael cipher (with variable block-size, etc.) instead of AES. Unfortunatelly I cant find a way to use it as full-disk-encrpytion.

---

This is a solely technical question. No general discussion about reasons 'why not to change' these parameters, please. Pertinent help much appriciated.

Comment: How are you planning on creating your volume?  Is this through some kind of installer UI/GUI?  Or are you creating them from the command line?

Comment: Preferably GUI, because I'm new to this. I'm using Ubuntu like operating systems. I used Truecrypt Full-Disk-Encryption (with boot-key) before and I want to replace it with Linux built in fde-support.

Answer (score 0):

When creating your volume with cryptsetup, one of the most common Linux FDE solutions, you can pass a number of options specifying various parameters for your volume being created.

They are pretty fully documented in the [cryptsetup man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cryptsetup).

When using the setting up an encrypted volume using the text-based Debian/Ubuntu installer you can choose the algorithm, and parameters related to it.  From what I can see booting a Deb 7.x/Ubuntu 14.04 the cipher selection is limited to: aes/blowfish/serpent/twofish.

Comment: Thanks! I improved my question since AES doesnt allow change of block-size. I'm really looking for native Rijndael cipher.

Comment: As far as I know there is no support for Rijndael in the [kernel](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/crypto?id=refs/tags/v3.17.4).  Kernel support is basically required for FDE.

Comment: I see... Since its not supported in _this_ OS's Kernel versions. Is there *any* other OS where the Kernel actually supports native Rijndael? Or is it very difficult to tweak an existing Kernel?